# Почему один и тот-же код выполняется по разному?

Tags: sublime-text-3

Почему один и тот-же код выполняется по-разному?

```
<!-- modal itself -not working -->
<div class="modal fade" id="reg-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="model-header bg-dark">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Get the Latest Updates</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body bg-dark">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo inventore veniam itaque fugiat saepe doloremque explicabo, voluptatem aut sed recusandae officia eveniet, quidem fuga similique rerum? Iure repellendus aperiam magni?</p>
        <label for="modal-email" class="form-label">Your email adress:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="modal-email" placeholder="e.g mario@example.com">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer bg-dark">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- modal itself - working -->
<!--   <div class="modal fade" id="reg-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Get the Latest Updates</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body bg-dark">
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, exercitationem laboriosam nihil minus voluptatibus harum aliquam consequatur pariatur inventore dignissimos illum excepturi ratione ipsum sit iusto alias eligendi fugit laborum?</p>
          <label for="modal-email" class="form-label">Your email address:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal-email" placeholder="e.g. mario@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer bg-dark">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> -->
```

[image: Not working] - not working
[image: Working] - working

Comment: Код не один и тот же. Если вы не видите различия на глаз — загоните оба кода в какой-нибудь инструмент для просмотра различий

Comment: Ага в какой-нибудь DIFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сайт https://text-compare.com/

4 строчка кода  `<div class="model-header bg-dark"> (not working)`
4 строчка кода   `<div class="modal-header bg-dark"> (working)`